# How can two directives (that are not nested in HTML) communicate with each other?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

im pretty new to angularJS and I got a question (hope it's not that dumb):

I got 2 directives (not nested):

```
<div directive1></div>
<div directive2></div>
```

Now i want the directives to talk to each other with a controller (Ive defined a 'controller: ' in directive1):

```
myApp
    .directive('directive2', function () {
        return {
            require: "^directive1",

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, directive1Ctrl) {
                directive1Ctrl.doSomething();
            }
        };
    });
```

**BUT** Im always getting 'Controller not Found' Exception.. (Im not that sure about the ^ cause its only for searching upwards through parents).

Is it not possible to use the Controller defined in directive1 from directive2 if theyre not nested?
Do i have to use a 'seperate' Controller which both require to work with each other?

Comment: What stops you from having multiple of the same directives ? ie 2 directive1's and 1 directive2 who talks to whom ?

Comment: its for a little feature i want to implement... there i need 2 different components talking to each other, wich are not nested

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just bind the same variable to both and watch it?

Comment: With your code , directive1 should have a controller defined , which would be exposing a method "doSomething" on "this" . 
Reference :: http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives-part-two/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do i have to use a 'seperate' Controller which both require to work with each other?

This is close.  The standard way to share data and functionality between different pieces of your application (two controllers, two directives, a directive and a controller, etc.) is to provide that data or functionality in a service.  This service can then be injected into any application component that requires it.

In your case, you could create a service that provides the `doSomething` function and inject it into both `directive1` and `directive2`.

Comment: thats the answer i expected :(... thought about letting the directives talk via the scope.. but i think the service could be more robust.. thanks anyways ;)

Answer (score 3):

if you set `require: "^directive1",` your directive 2 must be in directive 1:

```
<div directive1>
    <div directive2></div>
</div>
```

You can also use "?directive1" which makes it optional.

Simple put: there are two types of controllers: directive controllers and the normal ones.

With controllers you can set values in the scope that will be updated in the view.
This is a plunkr with one controller and two directives: http://plnkr.co/edit/IicvQfuv8LMOb4iVQen5

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('directive1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span>{{bar}}</span>'
    }
});

app.directive('directive2', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      template: '<b>{{bar}}</b>'
  }

});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.foo ="layla";
  $scope.bar ="hello";
});
```

and the html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  this is directive1: <div directive1>{{foo}}</div>.
  <br />
  this is directive2: <div directive2>{{foo}}</div>.
  Hello {{name}}!
</body>
```

Notice that directives are new elements that your browser can parse. They are an extension of HTML whose behaviour you defined in the app.directive() part.

When AngularJS finds `{{foo}}` it'll bind it to a scope that can be modified with the closer controller that has access to that scope. In this case, MainCtrl. You could also put MainCtrl in a `<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">...</div>`

With your code you get controller not found because it's going up the tree to find a controller named directive1Ctrl, which never happens.